# Regex and ISO8601 formated DateTime 2016-10-18T00:00:00Z only

Tags: regex

I have format 2016-10-18T00:00:00Z.
Config:

```
var regexIso8601 = /^(\d{4}|\+\d{6})(?:-(\d{2})(?:-(\d{2})(?:T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{1,})(Z|([\-+])(\d{2}):(\d{2}))?)?)?)?$/;
```

But, It parse string "2322" to DateTime, I don't want that, I only parse 2016-10-18T00:00:00Z.

Comment: Couldn't just look up an ISO 8601 regex? Why re-invent that wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will check the string matches the ISO date format.

The only regex that is used is

- `\d` digit
- `{n}` count of matches

There is no need to use capture's if we are not using the values anywhere.

Then we just use the `RegExp.prototype.test` method on the input string.

```js
const isISOFormat = str => /\+*\d{4,6}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2,3}Z/.test(str)

console.log(
  isISOFormat('2016-10-18T00:00:00Z'),
  isISOFormat('2016-10-18')
)
```

Comment: "Why not"? Because *Date.parse* is implementation dependent. There are date formats that will be parsed in some but not others, and some date formats are parsed differently in different implementations. Also, just because *Date.parse* returns a number doesn't mean that it parsed the date correctly.

Comment: @juongDavid I have edited my answer to use only regex

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very helpful for me